# Converting pixel grid to contours?

Tags: python, arrays

I have a pixel grid, which can be any kind of 2D array (numpy array for instance) with each value representing a color (max 5 different colors). I'm looking to display it in an OpenGL context, but drawing pixel by pixel is both inefficient and stupid. What I'd like to do is to regroup all adjacent pixel of the same color into one shape, so I can draw those shapes.

Basically, I want to be able to do this:
[image]
Going from a 2D array of points to a list of shapes (a shape being a list of vertices).

I have no idea how to proceed, so I'm looking for anything that can do the job, like any algorithm in any language or any Python Library that can do that.

Comment: Do you need the black line between the shapes in your rendering? Otherwise you could simply load the 2D array as a texture, and render the whole thing as a texture mapped quad.

Comment: No I don't, but I want the result to be independant from scaling (I want to use this to display zoom-able maps), and, unless I'm mistaken, scaling textures is going to look bad. I'm looking for a vector solution.

Comment: I can't think of a reason why it should look bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know you're asking for a vector solution, but I believe that the simple and obvious approach could work just fine for you, and will likely perform better.

I would load your color data into a texture, using a call sequence like (sorry about the C notation, but you should be able to translate this to python bindings easily):

```
GLuint texId = 0;
glGenTexture(1, &texId);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texId);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA8, width, height, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, colorData);
```

where `width` and `height` are the number of squares in horizontal and vertical direction, and `colorData` an array with the color for each square in RGB format.

Then it's important to choose the right sampling parameters. Since sharp edges between texels are desirable here, we want "nearest" sampling, instead of the "linear" that is more commonly used for image type textures. This will result in a sharp transition between the squares, instead of interpolating the colors between them:

```
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
```

Then, to render your grid, you render one single textured quad using this texture.

The only advantage I can think of that a vector solution would have over this is if you want to use multisampled anti-aliasing (aka MSAA). Since MSAA only does anti-aliasing on primitive edges, it would not help for the "edges" where you have color transitions between two squares. With a vector based solution, where you render each region as a separate primitive, you would get anti-aliasing for those edges.

As long as you just scale the image during display, the aliasing should not be a problem, though. That would only really come into play if you also wanted to rotate it.

Comment: With the sharp edges that's exactly what I was looking for, guess that's way easier like this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use `np.extract` function in `numpy` i think it can be helpful ! this is an example of it :

```
import numpy as np
arr = np.arange(12).reshape((3, 4))
condition = np.mod(arr, 3)==0 # base on this condition the function extract the special arrays
print np.extract(condition, arr)
```

and this is result :

```
[0 3 6 9]
```

then you can concatenate this array with `numpy.concatenate((a1, a2, ...), axis=0)` function ! read more at : http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/index.html